# Typescript union types is misleading

Tags: typescript, types, union

following the code snippet :

```
interface PalPay {
  email: string;
  someCode: string;
}

interface CreditCard {
  cardNumber: string;
  securityCode: string;
}

const payment: PayPal | CreditCard = {email: 'd@d.d', cardNumber: '1234', securityCode: 'abc'};
```

I managed to create a CreditCard object that has an `email` field.
How am I suppose to use typescript to create an object which is either CreditCard or PalPay?
what is the point of this behaviour anyways? in what case does this come in useful?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types

Comment: it adds typings so you can see what the object expects so it errors before compile, instead of at runtime like vanilla javascript does

Comment: Remember: [`If we have a value that has a union type, we can only access members that are common to all types in the union.`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Comment: it's useful when you're expecting one of those objects but for creating an object with a similar interface is not really useful. i mean, you can't do `{email: 'd@d.d', cardNumber: '1234', securityCode: 'abc'}` and have a mixed of those two objects.

Comment: TypeScript does not have "exclusive unions", as long as the value is assignable to one of the members of the union it is valid. See: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10575#issuecomment-242919644

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing the union type there. It is not meant to combine two different entities and to merge it together. It is meant to be used as a parameter type which can be handled in the respective function e.g.

```
interface PayPal {
  email: string;
  someCode: string;
  pay: () => void;
}

interface CreditCard {
  cardNumber: string;
  securityCode: string;
  pay: () => void;
}


handlePayment = (payType: PayPal | CreditCard) => {
   payType.pay();
}
```

Here I added the `pay` function to the interfaces which you can call in `handlePayment` on the union type of `Paypal | CreditCard`.

Comment: That's a more typical use-case but how does it explain why `handlePayment({ email: "", cardNumber: "", securityCode: "", pay() { } })` would be allowed?

Comment: Our answers seem to be complementary, definitely this is a good use of unions. I usually think type guars when unions are involved, but common fields is also a good use :)

Answer (score 0):

Union types define an object that can be either of the constituents of the union, so in your example `payment` can be either `PayPal` or `CreditCard`. You can use these when at runtime, `payment` may be either or, maybe the user can select the payment method. Union types are usually associated with type guards or discriminated unions. See here for [more](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types)

So in your example maybe a more realistic example would be:

```
interface PayPal {
    type: "paypal"
    email: string;
    someCode: string;
}

interface CreditCard {
    type: "credit"
    cardNumber: string;
    securityCode: string;
}

declare var userOption: boolean;
let payment: PayPal | CreditCard;
if (userOption) {
    payment = {
        type: "credit",
        cardNumber: '1234', securityCode: 'abc'
    }
} else {
    payment = {
        type: 'paypal',
        email: 'd@d.d', someCode: 'abc'
    }
}
// Later, we can check the type field, 
// and since this field is present on both interfaces 
// and typed to a string literal type 
// the compiler can determine the type of payment 
// in the branches if statement 
if (payment.type === 'credit') {
    console.log(payment.cardNumber); // payment is of type CreditCard
} else {
    console.log(payment.email);// payment is of type PayPal
}
```